# Identity Specifiaction is No, but the error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column ',

Tags: sql, insert, identity

I would like to copy articles to a new collection.

I tried an query but the follow error was displayed:

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'intArticleCollectionId'"

I have searched on internet for a solution. Till now i have the following query:

```
DECLARE @lastID int
DECLARE @lastID = Last_ID from LastIdentifiers where Tablename ='WA_ARTICLECOLLECTIONS'

INSERT INTO WA_ARTICLECOLLECTIONS (intArticleCollectionId,intArticleId,intCollectionId,chvArticleNr,chvFabricDescription,inyActive)
SELECT 
    IDENTITY(int, @lastID , 1) AS ID, intArticleCollectionId,intArticleId,4,chvArticleNr,chvFabricDescription,inyActive 
FROM 
    WA_ARTICLECOLLECTIONS 
WHERE intCollectionId = 5
```

This is also not helping me, can somebody adivice me how to change this.

I know the solution is to change in the design to set Identity ON, but that is for us not a solution ;-(.

Comment: The [`IDENTITY` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189838.aspx) is only useful for `SELECT ... INTO`. Why can't you change the design? Even if you correct the syntax you still have race conditions and even if you correct the race conditions then you will have blocking.

Comment: That are team agreements. The programmer would like to generate the last ID from a table, like the example LastIdentifiers. For me it's also strange, because it a nice feature to generate this automatic. Why you should not use it!!!
Any way that is team problem ;-(. Can you help me with the query? Is there a way to implement this way?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the best solution would be to redesign the table in order to benefit from the `IDENTITY` type. But this is not always possible and here is the solution i had when facing the same problem:

```
DECLARE @lastId   INT
DECLARE @newItems TABLE (id                   INT  IDENTITY(1,1)
                        ,articleId            INT
                        ,collectionId         INT
                        ,articleNr            VARCHAR(20)
                        ,fabricDescription    VARCHAR(256)
                        ,active               BIT)

SET @lastId = (SELECT MAX(AC.intArticleCollectionId)
               FROM WA_ARTICLECOLLECTIONS AC)

INSERT INTO @newItems(articleId, collectionId, articleNr, fabricDescription, active)
SELECT AC.intArticleId
    ,4
    ,AC.chvArticleNr
    ,AC.chvFabricDescription
    ,AC.inyActive 
FROM WA_ARTICLECOLLECTIONS AC
WHERE AC.intCollectionId = 5

INSERT INTO WA_ARTICLECOLLECTIONS (intArticleCollectionId,intArticleId,intCollectionId,chvArticleNr,chvFabricDescription,inyActive)
SELECT @lastId + I.id
    ,articleId
    ,collectionId
    ,articleNr
    ,fabricDescription
    ,active
FROM @newItems I
```

You'll probably need to adapt the column types of the table `@newItems`, but the goal is to show you my approach to solve the problem.

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.